# Save order of set in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, linkedhashset, persistent-set

I have two collections, which  by default are set to PersistentSet by hibernate. The issue is that under the hood hibernate casts them to HashSet, but I want them to be set to LinkedHashSet, as I want to preserve the order in which the elements are added.

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<String> responsibilities;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<String> requirements;
```

I have tried a couple of things, but without success

```
public void setResponsibilities(LinkedHashSet<String> responsibilities) {
    this.responsibilities = responsibilities;
}

public void setRequirements(LinkedHashSet<String> requirements) {
    this.requirements = requirements;
}
```

The other thing I tried was:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<String> requirements = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: hibernate 5 spring boot 2+

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#collections-sorted 
Seems that this can be done using SortedSet or just try using below solution:

```
@OrderBy("created DESC")
private Set<MyEntity> entities;
```

Comment: I have tried your solution and it didn't do the job, also please note that my set is of String, not of a custom object